# Use custom test function in bash conditional statement

Tags: bash, function

I have a bash function called `numeric` that returns either `1` or `0`.

```bash
numeric ()
{
  # compute k either 1 or 0
  echo "$k"
}
```

How can I use this function in a conditional statement to check if a variable `var` is numeric?

Comment: Do you actually need to check whether `var` is numeric, or is it sufficient to check whether it is `0` or `1`? If numeric in the general sense, is it (1) only positive integers, (2) integers in general, (3) also float values that would qualify?

Comment: I have the function `numeric` that does the job, but now I have to call it inside a conditional statement.  The function echoes either `1` (numeric) or `0` (non-numeric).

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Is the "conditional statement" an `if` statement?

Comment: An `if`, `while`, `case`.  I am not too prescriptive. Is in better to use `echo` or `return` for such things?

Comment: That depends. If you want the "simple" `if numeric` syntax, you should use `return`, because `if` checks the return status. If you want to handle this via a string, it is also possible but more cumbersome (you will need command substitutions and string checks). Unless you actually need to, I would recommend using the `return` method for this kind of feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that in the context of shell conditional expressions, a return value of `0` means "success" or "true", and a non-zero value means "failure" or "false", so I would recommend adapting the function so that it returns `0` if the argument is a numerical value.

Assuming that the "conditional statement" is an `if` construct, the following will work:

```bash
if numeric "$var"
then
   # Code if $var is numeric
else
   echo "$var is not numeric"
fi
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that instead of `echo $k` I use `return $k`?

Comment: @Vera Yes, see my comment under your question.

Answer (score 0):

use return

```
numeric ()
{
  # compute k either 1 or 0 || return 1
  echo "$k"
  return 0
}

numeric || exit 1
```